# create a virtual column that sums up values from a column in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables. production_table and items_table. an item or number of items are used for a production and those records have the same id_code eg...
production_table
|  id  |  product  |  price  |  quantity  |  id_code  |
| 10  |   shoe     |   75     |      32      |     1122    |
| 11  |   bowl     |   15     |      50      |     1144    |
and items_table
|  id  |  product  |  price  |  id_code  |
| 18  |   leather  |   15     |    1122    |
| 19  |   rubber  |   10     |    1122    |
| 18  |    glass   |   11     |    1144    |
| 19  |   rubber  |   10     |    1144    |
from the tables above, records in items_table with the same id_code were used to produce the record in production_table which also has the same id_code.Eg leather and ruber were used to produce shoe and they both have the id_code 122. 
Please how do I write a select query statement such that production records will be selected and a virtual column created to sum up prices of items used for that particular production with reference to the similar id_code the product and items share. So that I will have selected records like this : 
|  id  |  product  |  price  |  quantity  |  id_code  |  total_price_of_items  |
| 10  |   shoe     |   75     |      32      |     1122    |                 25               |
| 11  |   bowl     |   15     |      50      |     1144    |                 22               |
where 'total_price_of_items' is a virtual column

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: can you kindly write the sql query for me @Gordon_Linoff.

Comment: please it may be a duplicate question but this is my personal problem and I have no answer to it so kindly help me out..or provide the link to the supposed original question

Comment: select pt.id, pt.product, pt.price, pt.quantity, pt.id_code, sum(it.price) as total_price_of_items from production_table pt
inner join items_table it
on (pt.id_code = it.id_code)
group by pt.id, pt.product, pt.price, pt.quantity, pt.id_code;  Hope this helps you out